# D3 chloropleth map overlay is hiding tooltip

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I have created a d3 chloropleth map - the fill for each town represents donation data for a public radio station.  Mousing over the town produces a tooltip showing relevant data (ie: town name, donation amount).  I have also overlayed the map with circles representing the signal coverage of the radio station.  The problem is that the circle representing the station signal obscures the tooltip (which is based on the path for the town/city).  The tooltip works fine for towns that are not covered by the signal circle.  I tried moving the signal svg elements to load before the map, but then the map obscures the signal circles.  Any ideas on how to make the tooltip continue to function through the circles?  Thank you in advance.

The basic structure of the DOM is:

```
<div id="map">
    <div class="tooltip">
        <p>town</p>
        <p>amount</p>
    </div>
    <svg>
        <rect id="mapbg"></rect>
        <g class="state">
            <path .... </path>
            <path .... </path>
        </g>
        <g class="signals">
            <circle ... </circle>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the tooltip `div` after the `svg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the issue here is that the circles are receiving pointer events meant for the path beneath them. Assuming you don't need the circles to respond to mouse events, you can just set the style on the circles to `pointer-events: none`:

```
circle {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cnakf/ - if you remove `pointer-events: none`, you'll see that the rect no longer responds.